# Difference between Spring JDBCTemplate ResultSetExtractor and Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I do have a large MySQL database table (more than 1 million records). I need to read all data and do some processing on them using java language.

I want to make sure that the java process shouldn't consume more memory by taking the entire result set in memory.

While looking at cursor based implementations, I found some options,

1. Using Spring JDBCTemplate override ResultSetExtractor or RowCallbackHandler and reading row sequentially.
2. Other options using Spring Batch JDBCCursorItemReader/JDBCPagingItemReader.

Can someone explain what is the difference between these two options ?

Comment: the tag batch-file is meant for batch programming, which involves creating a batch-file that executes cmd commands. It should not be used when asking about Spring batch, or operations on a batch of files. For more information, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)

Comment: it's clear from name itself that spring batch is used for some batching task that run periodically or scheduled where is `JDBCTempllate` abstracts all JDBC related complexities like opening connections, making statements, reading result-set and finally closing all of them back with handing checked `SQLException`. now it depends how and where do you want to use it?

Comment: @DennisvanGils, Corrected it now.

Comment: @Braj, From name it is clear, but functionality wise I want to know the difference. I ran a simple program that reads data using ResultSetExtractor as well as JdbcCursorItemReader. For me, JDBCTemplate ResultSetExtractor took more time than JdbcCursorItemReader. I don't understand the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 seems better with some internal batching at your application side, if you require any batching.

JdbcCursorItemReader opens a new connection and hence will not participate in your application transaction. See the API at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html This API is part of spring batch. If you are writing a batch processing application then it will be well suited. See spring batch